# How to display modal in front of fullscreened video tag (React-Player)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, html5-video, fullscreen

I am working with a modal that is opened when the **hotkey** is clicked in React.
For example, if you press "a", then it opens the modal.
But when a video is playing on fullscreen mode, it hides the modal, so I cannot even see if the modal is opened behind the video tag.

Video playback is handled by '**React-Player**'.
I tried setting `z-index: 0` for video tag, and `z-index: 1000000` for modal, but not working.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can try fiddling with the `z-index` style property on the modal.

Comment: @tromgy I tried with z-index already

Comment: @Julius0505 Note that only one element can be fullscreened. Try putting both the video and modal into one container element (Div), then fullscreen that specific container. So make a Div (with some `id` setting for later access). **(1)** Make a test button to click (can be even click on text or image) and its function would do a `document.getElementById("your_Div_ID").requestFullscreen();` **(2)** Since the video tag's own fullscreen button is controlling only the video element, you'll have to lose it with `<video controls controlsList="nofullscreen">` and then make your own custom FS button.